# Gallery post images on homepage?

Tags: images, gallery

I have a post with image gallery, it has 10 images. Can I get the direct link to the images in the post, so that I can display first 5 images on the homepage?

Answer (score 2):

You could use this loop for fetching the images from current post.

```
<?php
$images = get_posts(array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));

if( $image ) {
    foreach($images as $image) :
        echo wp_get_attachment_link( $image->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
    endforeach;
}
?>
```

reference:

1. [wp_get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link)
2. [wp_get_attachment_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your child themes functions file and change the image I.D's to match the ones you want included in the gallery.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpsites_front_page_gallery' );
function wpsites_front_page_gallery() {
if ( is_home() ) {
echo do_shortcode('[gallery columns="5" link="file" ids="45266,45258,45250,45229,45227" orderby="rand"]');
}}
```

[image]

Change the wp_head hook to any WordPress or theme specific hook for positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Next Gen Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/)
you can then install an additional plugin which allows widgets
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery-sidebar-widget/

If you are using WordPress own Image Library and Gallery function try this plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fx-gallery-widget/